# How to check the filesize?

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

I have the text file with different sizes, so i want to delete the file where filesize = 0 kb.

How to make a vb6 code for deleting the 0 kb files.

Need vb6 code Help

Comment: Why would you be using vb6? Legacy code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [FileLen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262742(VS.60).aspx) function to check the file size.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FileLen function. See here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=498720

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
Sub DeleteZeroLengthFile(ByRef sFilePath As String)
' Inputs:  sFilePath        Filename or path name of file to be tested.
' Outputs: <None>
' In/Outs: <None>
' Errors:  Will raise error if file doesn't exist, is inaccessible, is locked, or user
'          doesn't have permissions.

    If FileLen(sFilePath) = 0 Then
        Kill sFilePath
    End If

End Sub
```