# VB6 - How to create another log file if reach atleast 5mb

Tags: vb6

The application is hanging up when it the log file reached 5mb. I just want to create another log file or incremental log file when reached certain size and write into this file. Could you provide some sample or functions that I can use. Below is my current function and planning to use FileLen to check file size.

TIA.

```
Public Sub LogTraces(ByVal folderName As String, ByVal sLocation As String, _
                     ByVal message As String)
                               
    Dim intN As Integer
    
    intN = FreeFile(1)

    Open sLocation & "\" & UCase(folderName) & "\" & UCase(folderName) & "_LOG_" & Format(Now, "MMDDYYYY") & ".log" For Append Shared As #intN
    'Open sLocation & "\LOGS\" & ConnectionID & "-" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".log" For Append Shared As #intN

    Print #intN, Format(Now, "[mmddyyyy HH:mm:ss]") & ": " & message
        
    Close #intN
   
End Sub
```

Comment: This will help you to find file size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736980/how-to-check-the-filesize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked your code by using a function to calculate the file name.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LogTraces(ByVal folderName As String, ByVal sLocation As String, ByVal message As String)
   Dim fn As Integer: fn = FreeFile(1)
   Open GetFileName(folderName, sLocation) For Append Shared As #fn
   Print #fn, Format(Now, "[mmddyyyy HH:mm:ss]") & ": " & message
   Close #fn
End Sub

Public Function GetFileName(ByVal folderName As String, ByVal sLocation As String) As String
   Dim i As Integer
   
   'get 'base' file name and make sure it exists
   GetFileName = sLocation & "\" & UCase(folderName) & "\" & UCase(folderName) & "_LOG_" & Format(Now, "MMDDYYYY") & ".log"
   If Dir(GetFileName) = "" Then CreateFile GetFileName
   
   'if the file is too big (pick some file size in bytes)
   Do While FileLen(GetFileName) > 5242880
      'get new file name by appending a number and make sure it exists
      i = i + 1
      GetFileName = sLocation & "\" & UCase(folderName) & "\" & UCase(folderName) & "_LOG_" & Format(Now, "MMDDYYYY") & "_" & i & ".log"
      If Dir(GetFileName) = "" Then CreateFile GetFileName
   Loop
End Function

Public Sub CreateFile(ByVal FileName As String)
   Dim fn As Integer: fn = FreeFile(1)
   Open FileName For Output As #fn
   Close #fn
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll apply this to my code.

Comment: Log file is now incrementing however it logged 'File not Found" error on some messages.  Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: `FileLen` will throw that error if the file has not been created yet.  Are you using `GetFileName` as shown above?

Comment: Yes, I applied your script, and the log is created incrementally however error 53 or "File not Found" occurs sometimes while logging the messages.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists at the time you log the message?  Again, `FileLen` will throw that error if the file does not exist.  I did update the code to make it a little more robust, however I am not convinced it will solve your problem since you say it only fails on occasion.